# How to install libgtk2-dev:i386 without removing libgtk2-dev:armhf? Or what to do to cross-compile for i386 and armhf?

Tags: gcc, arm, gtk, cross-compiling, i386

I'm struggling trying to cross-compile a wxWidgets app for a BBB from a Debian 9 PC.
After a lot of failures, i've found what seemed to be the solution: multiarch. So i added an armhf architecture, installed the arm-gcc compiler, the links:armhf and the libgtk2.0-dev:armhf, twithout caring too much about the removal of what was already present 'cause i thought it was garbage due to so much different attempts.

Now i tried to recompile the widgets for the i386 and it complains about the lack of the GTK2-dev libraries.

The apt-get install command gives me this:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev:i386
    Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
    Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
    Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
    I seguenti pacchetti sono stati installati automaticamente e non sono più richiesti:
      gir1.2-atk-1.0:armhf gir1.2-freedesktop:armhf gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:armhf gir1.2-glib-2.0:armhf gir1.2-pango-1.0:armhf libasan3:armhf libatk1.0-0:armhf
      libatomic1:armhf libavahi-client3:armhf libavahi-common-data:armhf libavahi-common3:armhf libbsd0:armhf libc6-dev:armhf libcairo-gobject2:armhf
      libcairo-script-interpreter2:armhf libcairo2:armhf libcups2:armhf libdatrie1:armhf libdbus-1-3:armhf libexpat1:armhf libexpat1-dev:armhf libffi6:armhf
      libfontconfig1:armhf libfreetype6:armhf libgail-common:armhf libgail18:armhf libgcc-6-dev:armhf libgcrypt20:armhf libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:armhf
      libgirepository-1.0-1:armhf libglib2.0-0:armhf libgmp10:armhf libgnutls30:armhf libgomp1:armhf libgpg-error0:armhf libgraphite2-3:armhf
      libgssapi-krb5-2:armhf libgtk2.0-0:armhf libharfbuzz-gobject0:armhf libharfbuzz-icu0:armhf libharfbuzz0b:armhf libhogweed4:armhf libice-dev:armhf
      libice6:armhf libicu57:armhf libidn11:armhf libjbig0:armhf libjpeg62-turbo:armhf libk5crypto3:armhf libkeyutils1:armhf libkrb5-3:armhf
      libkrb5support0:armhf liblz4-1:armhf liblzo2-2:armhf libnettle6:armhf libp11-kit0:armhf libpango-1.0-0:armhf libpangocairo-1.0-0:armhf
      libpangoft2-1.0-0:armhf libpangoxft-1.0-0:armhf libpcre16-3:armhf libpcre3-dev:armhf libpcre32-3:armhf libpcrecpp0v5:armhf libpixman-1-0:armhf
      libpng-dev:armhf libpng16-16:armhf libpthread-stubs0-dev:armhf libsm-dev:armhf libsm6:armhf libstdc++-6-dev:armhf libstdc++6:armhf libsystemd0:armhf
      libtasn1-6:armhf libthai0:armhf libtiff5:armhf libubsan0:armhf libx11-6:armhf libx11-dev:armhf libxau-dev:armhf libxau6:armhf libxcb-render0:armhf
      libxcb-render0-dev:armhf libxcb-shm0:armhf libxcb-shm0-dev:armhf libxcb1:armhf libxcb1-dev:armhf libxcomposite-dev:armhf libxcomposite1:armhf
      libxcursor-dev:armhf libxcursor1:armhf libxdamage-dev:armhf libxdamage1:armhf libxdmcp-dev:armhf libxdmcp6:armhf libxext-dev:armhf libxext6:armhf
      libxfixes-dev:armhf libxfixes3:armhf libxft2:armhf libxi-dev:armhf libxi6:armhf libxinerama-dev:armhf libxinerama1:armhf libxrandr-dev:armhf
      libxrandr2:armhf libxrender-dev:armhf libxrender1:armhf linux-libc-dev:armhf meld zlib1g-dev:armhf
    Usare "sudo apt autoremove" per rimuoverli.
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      gir1.2-gtk-2.0 libatk1.0-dev libcairo2-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev
      libicu-dev libpango1.0-dev libpixman-1-dev libxft-dev
    Pacchetti suggeriti:
      libcairo2-doc icu-doc
    I seguenti pacchetti saranno RIMOSSI:
      gir1.2-gtk-2.0:armhf libatk1.0-dev:armhf libcairo2-dev:armhf libfontconfig1-dev:armhf libfreetype6-dev:armhf libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:armhf
      libglib2.0-dev:armhf libgraphite2-dev:armhf libgtk2.0-dev:armhf libharfbuzz-dev:armhf libicu-dev:armhf libpango1.0-dev:armhf libpixman-1-dev:armhf
      libxft-dev:armhf
    I seguenti pacchetti NUOVI saranno installati:
      gir1.2-gtk-2.0 libatk1.0-dev libcairo2-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libgraphite2-dev libgtk2.0-dev
      libharfbuzz-dev libicu-dev libpango1.0-dev libpixman-1-dev libxft-dev
    0 aggiornati, 14 installati, 14 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
    È necessario scaricare 0 B/31,8 MB di archivi.
    Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 5.458 kB di spazio su disco.
    Continuare? [S/n] n
    Interrotto.
```

I googled a lot, and seems to me that the libgtk are not ready for multiarch.
But my understanding is limited, and so i'm (again) stuck against a wall.

What should i do to compile for both the architectures (linking the right libraries)?

Could i just download the two debs and keep them extracted on another folder? If yes, how to link them corretcly?

Should i change the control file inside the .dev files? if yes, how exactly?

Comment: 1) What is BBB? 2) ISTM this question is more about package management rather than compiling (though it is about that too). I suggest tagging appropriately. 3) Lastly, not everyone on stackoverflow knows Italian; more people would be willing to read the listing and help if you provide a version in English.

Comment: `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev:i386` should do the trick to get the english version.